$set not working for runCommand update when trying to copy values into a new value
So I have a collection called dummyCollection where I’ve defined two string properties called username and passoword. Username is declared as string and password as binData. I want to use these two to create a new property called user which would serve as a key value map. I want to update the exisiting collections in the data base so that the current value for username and password would be used to construct this new users object. This doesn’t seem to work. Instead, the values from username and password are copied as string literal. Unfortunately, I can only do update via runCommand. Anything I’m doing wrong here?
    {
    "update": "dummyCollection",
    "updates":
    [
        {
            "q":
            {
                "username":
                {
                    "$exists": true
                },
                "password":
                {
                    "$exists": true
                }
            },
            "u":
            {
                "$set":
                {
                    "users.dummyUser":
                    {
                        "username": "$username",
                        "password": "$password"
                    }
                }
            },
            "multi": true
        }
    ]
}


What do you mean by "Unfortunately, I can only do update via runCommand." ? Is updateMany not working or is it your requirement to only use runCommand?

@aneroid I can only use runCommand because I have to do this via Liquibase MongoDB extensions which supports a limited number of MongoDb commands. But I managed to find a workaround which works using runCommand aggregate. This still doesn't solve this issue.

Workaround:
{
"aggregate": "dummyCollection",
"cursor": {},
"pipeline": [
{
"$addFields": {
"users.dummyUser.username": "$username",
"users.dummyUser.password": "$password"
}
},
{
"$out": "dummyCollection"
}
],
"allowDiskUse": true
}

Edit your question with that workaround and the info you have put in the comments.

Also, your workaround with aggregate should work. Mongo Playground.

In order to use the document's fields in the update part of the query, like $set or $addFields, it needs to be a pipeline with [ <stage1>, <stage2>, etc.]. Even if it's just one stage. So the update part should look like [{ $set: { ... } } ].
db.dummyCollection.update({
  "username": { "$exists": true },
  "password": { "$exists": true }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "users.dummyUser": {
        "username": "$username",
        "password": "$password"
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})

MongoPlayground
The runCommand equivalent is:
db.dummyCollection.runCommand({
  "update": "dummyCollection",
  "updates":
  [
    {
      "q":
      {
        "username": { "$exists": true },
        "password": { "$exists": true }
      },
      "u":
      [
        {
          "$set":
          {
            "users.dummyUser":
            {
              "username": "$username",
              "password": "$password"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "multi": true
    }
  ]
})

